# Validation accuracy with Keras fit_generator is diffferent than when calculating manually using the same data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am training a model with `fit_generator` and splitting the data into train and validation set. During training I also evaluate with the validation data on an accuracy metric and I get a `val_acc` of 0.9519.

The problem is, I also evaluate the accuracy of the model by calling the validation generator manually, using python `next` function. When evaluating this way, I get a validation accuracy of 0.74.

Why is there such a big difference between the two accuracy metrics when I am evaluating on the same data?

Here is a snippet of my code below. I hope somebody can help me with problem!

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.1,
    fill_mode='nearest')

train_gen = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size = (224,224),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    class_mode = 'categorical',
    subset = 'training')

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.1,
    fill_mode='nearest')

val_gen = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size = (224,224),
    batch_size = 1,
    class_mode = 'categorical',
    subset = 'validation',
    shuffle = False)

model.fit_generator(train_gen,
                    steps_per_epoch = train_gen.samples // batch_size,
                    validation_data=val_gen,
                    validation_steps=val_gen.samples,
                    initial_epoch =  history.epoch[-1]+1,
                    epochs=10)
```

After I call fit_generator, I get a val_acc score of 0.95, here is the
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwSIv.png) for reference.

And then evaluating manually, using python `next` function on `val_gen`:

```
predictions = []
labels = []

val_gen.reset()

# batch_size of val_gen = 1
for _ in range(val_gen.samples):
    X_val, y_val = next(val_gen)
    pred = model.predict(X_val)
    predictions.append(pred)
    labels.append(y_val)
predictions = np.array(predictions)
predictions = np.argmax(predictions,axis=2)
labels = np.array(labels)
labels = np.argmax(labels, axis=2)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy = accuracy_score(predictions,labels)
```

Using sklearn accuracy_score I get 0.74.

Comment: try removing the parameter `validation_steps=val_gen.samples` and see if this problem persists.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck, the problem still persists even after removing this parameter.

Comment: @Fmak might be wrong, but didn't `.reset()` completely reset the generator, i.e. the RNG will return different random rotation, rescale, ...?!

Comment: This looks wrong: val_gen = train_datagen.flow_from_directory, as you are using the training generator to produce validation data.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro thanks for pointing that out! I fixed this in my code, but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

This is, of course, quite "hacky", but in extension of my assumption I did a quick test:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.datasets import cifar10
import numpy as np

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.1,
    fill_mode='nearest')

val_gen = val_datagen.flow(
    (x_train, y_train),
    batch_size = 1,
    shuffle = False)

print("first try")
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(val_gen):
    print(x.mean())
    if i >= 5:
        break

val_gen.reset()

print()
print("second try")
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(val_gen):
    print(x.mean())
    if i >= 5:
        break
```

After calling `.reset()`, we will operate on the start of the data again, but as you see, the mean as different in both runs:

```
first try
0.41334367
0.5364689
0.49460053
0.32310262
0.33062425
0.34027505

second try
0.41919175
0.5279837
0.48176324
0.32459995
0.34152344
0.38571596
```

Thus I would assume your problem is not calling `.fit()` over manual iteration, but actually the `val_datagen` itself. You assigned random operations like `rescale`, `rotation_range`, ..., which, after `.reset()` was being called on that object, will return different results.

Why did I use `.mean()` on the image data? Just to have *some* quick operation that would return different results if the images contain different information.

You would need to **seed** the backend (e.g. TensorFlow) of Keras in order to force the RNG to always produce the same random output. Or do not use random data augmentation on validation set in the first place.

Comment: Thanks! I took your suggestion and took out any data augmentation in the validation set, but the problem still persists.